# Vanilla Javascript Ajax call inside IIFE not responding

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hey guys I'm running an IIFE and an ajax call and it seems to not respond at all...

```
    var $ = {
     core:function(u){
       return new $.httpRequest(u);
     },
     httpRequest:function(url){
       var text;
       var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
           r.open("GET", url, true);
           r.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (this.readyState != 4 || this.status != 200) return; 
              text = this.responseText;
            };
           r.send();
          console.log(text);
          return text;
   }
 };
```

Is there something silly I am missing? Just been over this a few times and I have my hands full and hope that our savvy SO members could help out. Should I place the return inside the `onload`?

Comment: Does *Vanilla* really matter .. ?

Comment: In what sense? Meaning use jQuery then yes it does.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I understand what you emphasize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onreadystatechange function you assign is where you need to handle the `responseText`.  You need to either process it there or call some function and pass it the data.  Remember, the ajax call is asynchronous which means that you start it with your `r.send()`, your `$.httpRequest()` function finishes, your other javascript after it executes and then some time later the ajax call completes and calls your `onreadystatechange` function.  At that point, all you can do is to either process the data right there in that function or call some other function and pass the data to it.

Here's one way of doing it using a callback function that you pass into your httpRequest function:

```
   var $ = {
     core:function(u){
       return new $.httpRequest(u);
     },
     httpRequest:function(url, callback){
       var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
           r.open("GET", url, true);
           r.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return; 
             callback(r.responseText);
           };
           r.send();
   }

};
```

Example usage:

```
$.httpRequest("http://examplesite.com/myurl", function(data) {
    // write code here to process the data
});
```

Comment: No.  You can't return the data from your httpRequest function.  This is asynchronous programming and your httpRequest function has already long since finished.  Some time LATER your ajax call finishes and then and only then is the data available and you can do something with it.

Comment: Thanks again! Always there to help, you are ;)

Comment: I am getting some errors, though it may be on my part so please be patient as I analyze my coding

Comment: Ok error is coming from `callback(this.responseText);` as it is stating `undefined is not a function` should I use `cb.call(this,this.responseText);`

Comment: @EasyBB - that probably means you aren't passing the function to `$.httpRequest()` as the second argument as shown in my example usage.

Comment: You're right ;) I wasn't in the other functions that chain it together. I passed it in this function but not the core or anything else :/ My bad. thanks again